# I can't get my svg:hover to work

Tags: css, svg

I've been sitting here for 2 hours clicking on links and googling around the web to find a solution to my problem. The problem is that I cannot get my hovers to work on my SVG objects.

First of I tried to put the hover effect on a group("g") but I quickly realised that it doesn't work, so I decide to make rectangle("rect") to cover up the area I want to hover.
Here's the css:

```
#ipad-box {
   fill: blue;
}

#ipad-box:hover {
   fill: red;
}
```

And here's the object:

```
        <rect id="ipad-box" x="885.8" y="181.3" transform="matrix(0.9427 -0.3337 0.3337 0.9427 -72.968 368.1184)" class="st53" width="298.4" height="430.3"/>
```

Though here's the whole svg: (Warning: Very long)
https://pastebin.com/wyJv29nZ

I can't think of what I'm doing, and I'd really appreciate if someone would like to help

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, I tried your code on jsfiddle and it works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/as65zk9b/

Comment: @FurkanPoyraz
https://gyazo.com/da11dff775a178b9bb84ef37f04de669